# XAML: How to apply styling to ALL elements, even elements that have a Style set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

/edit:Windows 10 UWP app, which is using the new ThemeResources (so no StaticResources)

I want to center ALL my TextBlocks. I know I'd have to do this in my Application.Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

However, this does not work when a TextBlock has a Style set.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
```

I also know how to override the color in ThemeResources like above, but this ThemeResource does not have HorizontalAlignment set. Further, I don't want to add duplicate styling in my Resources, as I'm using different ThemeResources.

What I want to achieve is what is very easy in CSS:
    span { 
      text-alignment:center;
    }
... but I have no idea how to do this in XAML without a lot of duplicate code. It must be very easy I hope?

To clarify my question: I want to apply styling to ALL TextBlocks, TextBlocks with a style set, and TextBlock without a style set.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **BasedOn** parameter in **Style**, or remove **HorizontalAlignment** property in your **HeaderTextBlockStyle**

also check that **HorizontalAlignment** property can be inheritance in **HeaderTextBlockStyle** from current style, so you can set it manually for this item only

Comment: HeaderTextBlockStyle is a ThemeResource (new in 8.1 apps), and I cannot find a way to override that. BasedOn={StaticResource ..} or BasedOn={ThemedResource ..} don't work both.

Comment: try set HorizontalAlignment value manually for current control

Comment: Yeah that is working fine, but I want to apply it to ALL TextBlocks, those with a Style set to a ThemeResource, and those without a Style set.

Comment: well you can edit your ThemedResource adding the HorizontalAlignment

Comment: try this https://blog.tallan.com/2014/02/04/overriding-themeresources-in-windows-8-1-apps/

Comment: How to edit ThemedResource? They are built in.Yes, I've seen that, but it only talks about Brushes. Don't know how to apply this for HorizontalAlignment.

Comment: first of all search all keys of your style, then use it like brushes. To edit ThemedResource is to create a copy of this style, not empty

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't want to edit a ThemedResource. I don't want to add a style based on a themed resource. I just want to apply alignment to all text blocks, whether they have a style set or not. Only if the style explicitly sets the alignment it must use that one, otherwise use my "generic" alignment. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: or use StaticResource instead ThemeResource

Comment: "Update your WPF and framework" - Sorry but that does not make any sense.
And, even if I would use StaticResources, I would still have the same problem. As soon as a Style is set, a generic style is no longer applied. That's my point.